# How to change MySQL InnoDB cluster from single primary mode to multi primary mode?

Tags: mysql, innodb, installation, ubuntu, mysql-innodb-cluster

**My *goal* is to setup, in a lab environment, a MySQL InnoDB cluster in multi-primary mode.**

I have read much, but I cannot get this setup to work.

Ubuntu 16.04.3 server LTS x 3
SQL0 - SQL2

Ubuntu 16.04.3 server LTS x 2
REP0 - REP1

All server instances are in Virtual machine except REP0 is on bare metal and REP1 is off line.

Installed MySQL server 8.0 from Oracle APT repo using `mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb`.

These servers have been up and down with many config changes trying to find a setup that works.

Set MySQL server 8.0 with `Legacy Authentication Method` on all boxes.

My current `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is based on Justin Ellingwood @ [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04).

This is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` from [SQL0](https://pastebin.com/6U3985E1). This machine was at one time the primary in a single-primary setup that did not work correctly.

The other `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file are very similar to this one with the `# Host specific replication configuration` section changed.

The error I am trying to resolve now is from `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

```
[ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: 'It is not allowed to run single primary mode with 'enforce_update_everywhere_checks' enabled.'
```

Yes I do have these set in my.cnf because I want multi-primary mode. I do not want to run in single-primary mode.

```
loose-group_replication_single_primary_mode = OFF
loose-group_replication_enforce_update_everywhere_checks = ON
```

**Where, How, What else do I need to change for these to be in multi-primary mode and not error out?**

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you're not using [MySQL Shell and its AdminAPI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-introduction.html) to set up and manage your InnoDB cluster?

You can create a multi-primary cluster very easily using the AdminAPI. Example:

```
var cluster = dba.createCluster("myCluster", {multiPrimary: true})
```

Also, if you already have a running Group Replication group that you'd like to manage using the Shell you can simply "[adopt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-from-group-replication.html)" it:

```
var cluster = dba.createCluster("myCluster", {adoptFromGR: true})
```

And since 8.0.14, you can change a running InnoDB cluster from single-primary mode to multi-primary mode "live". The AdminAPI provides a function for that operation:

```
<Cluster.>switchToMultiPrimaryMode()>
```

Also, it is possible to switch back a running cluster to single-primary mode:

```
<Cluster.>switchToSinglePrimaryMode([instance])
```

And even to elect a member of the cluster to be the new primary:

```
<Cluster.>setPrimaryInstance(instance)
```

Please take a look at the blog post that announced those new features:

https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-innodb-cluster-changing-cluster-topology-modes-live/

And for further information check the official [userguide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-working-with-cluster.html#mysql-innodb-cluster-change-topology).

Cheers,

Miguel

Answer (score 0):

**This is a *HACK* to get multi-master cluster to work.**

This is *NOT* a good answer, but I have a working cluster...

First I deleted the 3 VM and re-created them. Used the instructions from Justin Ellingwood @ DigitalOcean.

...because these were fresh installs the test database read/write on all instances.

On REP0 the bare metal machine.

`sudo apt-get --purge remove sql*`

yes to remove tables

`sudo apt-get update`

do not see Oracle repos...

readd repos

`sudo dpkg -i /opt/mysql_InnoDB_cluster/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb`

`sudo apt-get update`

repos exist now.

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-shell`

SELECT: Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.x Compatibility)

At this point used the instructions from Justin Ellingwood @ DigitalOcean.

REP0 is now a read/write member.

This does *NOT* answer the question.

**What tables need to be emptied, deleted, or recreated to be able to change from single-master to multi-master cluster?**